ESLint Globals configuration for testing in general?
I'm using a testing library that allows suite to be used, and if I add Jest like this to the ESLint globals configuration in eslint.config.js it works for the test global, but not for suite.
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";

export default [
    // apply recommended rules to JS files
    
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.jest
            }
        }
    },
    {

        files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
        rules: eslint.configs.recommended.rules
    },
    {
        ignores: ["rollup.config.js", "web-test-runner.config.js", "src/index.bundle.js"]
    }
]

Is there are generic global for ESLint that we can use that will cover most of the generic testing globals?
This is the linting error:
/Users/oleersoy/Temp/Remove/fs-javascript-starter/src/hello-world.component.spec.js
  4:1  error  'suite' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Where does suite come from? Not Jest, right? I think “globals that a testing framework might define” would be a very bad preset. (Well, I also think that relying on globals instead of explicitly importing them isn’t a great idea to begin with.)

@open-wc/testing ... This is the javascript starter project that has all the dependencies .... https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-javascript-starter

So you’re not even using Jest? Just skimming this, but maybe @open-wc/eslint-config is appropriate, or just the env: {mocha: true} part of it. In short, use the env/globals/ESLint configuration package of whatever tools you’re actually using.

I'm sure there is something in ESLint that is part of the new globals configuration that will support it.  Perhaps it's just not documented yet.  The suite keyword is very common across all test frameworks, so it would make sense for ESLint to have something generic to support the cross section.

Why would you want to configure your linter with a set of globals that approximates the ones you have (if that even existed, which I don’t agree that it should – why are you sure of it?) when you could configure it with exactly the ones you actually have?

@Ry- If you have a solution that can be configured in eslint.config.js (Keeping the configuration for ESLint simple and inline with the new documentation) and something that allows people writing tests to not have to add comments per file that eliminate linting errors, then please provide an answer.  I'm all ears and I'm sure lots of other people will be grateful to you as well.

Pretty sure I already mentioned it!

@Ry- Please put it an an answer that you yourself have verified.  "Pretty sure" is leaves room for doubt.  Personally I don't see what it is you are talking about anywhere in the new documentation, so please provide an answer that I can easily test myself within eslint.config.js and if it works I'll check it off.

This purpose of this eslint.config.js is to provide users with a simple starting point for pure javascript projects that has eslint, etc. already scaffolded out for them.  So if you know of a generic way to configure eslint best for this project please point show it in an answer.  Here is the full project so you can also easily test this yourself.  https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-javascript-starter/tree/main

I’m not going to install your repo to test it, and I’m not going to write an answer because I think you’re asking the wrong question. It’s up to you to apply the advice in my comment to your situation.

@Ry- that's fine, but in all honesty I would have preferred if you simply did not comment if you don't know what it is you are talking about.  Please respect my time and your own.

I know what I’m talking about, which I was able to give you a whole list of solutions from cleanest (using imports instead of relying on globals) to least clean (grab bag of generic testing globals that does not actually exist). Good point on respecting my time, though.

@Ry- Your solutions don't fit the context, and thus are not solutions.  That is why you don't actually want to provide an answer or actually verify that your "Solution" works.  And you full well know this and you knew it at the start of this entire conversation as well.

OK - I studied the globals json file provided by the globals NPM package, and it looks like mocha is a good fit, in general, and for this question in particular.
I updated the config and this works.
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import globals from "globals";

export default [
    {
        languageOptions: {
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.mocha
            }
        }
    },
    // apply recommended rules to JS files
    {
        files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
        rules: eslint.configs.recommended.rules
    },
    {
        ignores: ["rollup.config.js", "web-test-runner.config.js"]
    }
]

